# Does Resharper 6.0 (current version) support Microsoft Visual Studio 11 Developer Preview or can it be made to?

Tags: visual-studio, resharper, visual-studio-2012, resharper-6.0

I've read articles that explain how to enable Visual Studio 2010 managed extensions to get them working with  Microsoft Visual Studio 11 Developer Preview

[Running VS2010 Gallery Extensions In VS11, Meet Git Source Control Provider](http://gurustop.net/blog/2011/09/20/running-dev11-vs11-visual_studio_11-extensions-extension_manager_gallery-git-scm-plugin-addon/)

However I haven't been able to apply the same logic to Resharper. Although it's a managed extension now, it doesn't appear to be packaged in a VSIX file, so I can't follow all the steps in the above mentioned article.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### No (For R#6.0)

Whilst I can't find an official looking page on JetBrain's resharper web site, I did find a reply from a JetBrain's engineer

> The upcoming ReSharper 6.1 will have initial experimental support for Visual
>   Studio vNext.

http://devnet.jetbrains.net/message/5320971#5320971

### Yes (For R#6.1)

Resharper 6.1 has now got experimental support for Visual Studio 11, albeit via a separate download to the normal 6.1 installer:  http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/download/index.html#related

Blog post explaining the current level of support in VS11: http://blogs.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2011/12/christmas-is-here-resharper-61-dotcover-12-and-dottrace-452-released/

Comment: Unfortunately the download seems to have been removed when they launched Resharper 7

Answer (score 3):

Resharper 6.0 does not support VS11.

The nightly builds of Resharper 6.1 though are now available, and **do support VS11**.

- To download Resharper for VS 11:
  http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/ReSharper/ReSharper+6.1+Nightly+Builds
- To learn more about Resharper 6.1:
  http://blogs.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2011/11/resharper-61-eap-opens-much-more-than-a-bugfix-release/
- For details on how the experience with VS11 in general is like, compared to VS2010:
  http://gurustop.net/blog/2011/11/10/notes-on-using-visual-studio-11-as-primary-ide-on-windows-7/

**Update:**

For notes on installing Resharper on VS 11, and small gotachas and solution, check this post as well:
http://gurustop.net/blog/2011/11/11/resharper-6-0-resharper-6-1-vs11-visual-studio-11-support-keyboard-shortcuts/

**Update 2:**

Since VS11 has been fully released as VS 2012, Resharper has released final version 6.1 (free for 6.0 owners), and 7.x for it already and they're working just nice. Wrote this update as the answer still gets up-votes (thank you).

Comment: Hi Meligy,
Jetbrains have removed the download links for the VISX files, so the steps on gurustop.net are no longer working.
[link]http://download-ln.jetbrains.com/resharper/ReSharper.v6.1.36.53.vs11.0.Vsix[/link] leads to a 404 now.

I don't suppose you could share a .visx file for us?

Comment: Hi, check http://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/entries/21206508-Where-can-I-download-an-old-previous-ReSharper-version- for older versions of Resharper inclding 6.1.

Comment: Thanks for the link.  I've been there already, but those downloads don't contain the visx file for visual studio 2012.

Comment: They have an installer. An MSI, just use that and it should install into VS.